# ASP.NET Core 6 getting Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1] Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection

Tags: .net-6.0, asp.net-core-6.0, kestrel

I am building a 5 method Web API application that needs to be secured with TLS in production. I have a gRPC server that works and when I use the same configuration in the Web API app, I am getting the following error:

> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1]
>
> Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
>
> System.IO.IOException: Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.OnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)
>
> dbug: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware[1]
> Failed to authenticate HTTPS connection.
> System.IO.IOException:  Received an unexpected EOF or 0 bytes from the transport stream.
>
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ReceiveBlobAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter)
> at System.Net.Security.SslStream.ForceAuthenticationAsync[TIOAdapter](TIOAdapter adapter, Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] reAuthenticationData, Boolean isApm)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Https.Internal.HttpsConnectionMiddleware.OnConnectionAsync(ConnectionContext context)

I ripped out all of the gRPC code in the Web API Program.cs file in lieu of trying to configure Kestrel in the `launchSettings.json` file.

The snippet below shows my current effort:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "Endpoints": {
      "HttpsInlineCertFile": {
        "Url": "https://localhost:30050",
        "Certificate": {
          "Path": "D:\\Development\\Certs\\MDevelopment.pfx",
          "Password": "xxxxxxxx"
        }
      }
    },
    "Certificates": {
      "Default": {
        "Path": "D:\\Development\\Certs\\MDevelopment.pfx",
        "Password": "xxxxxxxx"
      }
    }
  }
```

The development and production certs work in the gRPC case, and also for securing a mail server I have so I am confident the certs are good. I have tried so many things, I cannot tell you anything else of value.

Comment: Does the server answer ok when using the openssl command line tool? ```openssl s_client -connect <server>:443```

Comment: @Steve Miller, were you able to figure this one out?

Comment: I have a similar problem. I have a gRPC service hosted in a ASP Core .NET 6. In the first computer (develop computer) I can connect from an android device. But if I install this ASP in a second computer (real server) I get this error. I am using the same certificates, so I don't know which is the problem. It is a self signed certificate and self signed root certificate in it is not installed neither both computers.

Comment: I'm adding a comment here, as if I make the same comment under your new question, it may turn your post into a downvote magnet. I have removed most of the "rant" section from your new post, as that was the Stack Overflow equivalent of painting a target on your back and "flipping the bird" at readers. 

Comment: I know it is tempting to ask for special treatment when you're up against tough deadlines, but it is hard to state how counter-productive that is. The best analogy I can think of is attempting to push into a queue somewhere in rural England - it doesn't go down very well! Ditto on waffle and complaining - remove all of that, cut it down to technical writing and bare essentials. This is not a forum. Posts should be written in the format they are best preserved in (for the benefit of future readers).

Comment: I often offer this boilerplate advice: _Note that we prefer a technical style of writing here. We gently discourage greetings, hope-you-can-helps, thanks, advance thanks, notes of appreciation, regards, kind regards, signatures, please-can-you-helps, chatty material and abbreviated txtspk, pleading, how long you've been stuck, voting advice, meta commentary, etc. Just explain your problem, and show what you've tried, what you expected, and what actually happened_.

Answer (score 1):

@Buffoonism, @Alvaro: I tried many things in trying to overcome this error. I did find that the cert that was being used in production was not correct (the node name changed messing everything up...)

What I did was create a new cert to ensure I was using the correct keys to gen the certificate. Then, I changed the way the cert was being applied to the listener as such:

```
// Get the host name and port number to bind the service to.
kestrelServerOptions.ConfigureHttpsDefaults (httpsConnectionAdapterOptions => {
    httpsConnectionAdapterOptions.ServerCertificate = new X509Certificate2 (certPath, certPassword);
    httpsConnectionAdapterOptions.SslProtocols = SslProtocols.Tls12;
});
```

Once I made that change, everything started to work. @Microsoft, you really need to step up your documentation game! All of you examples surround using a dev cert which is easy. Using a production-grade cert requires more handling (such as trusting the cert) which could use waaaaaaay better examples!

I hope that helps!

Comment: Hi @Steve Miller, I'm having the same issue, could you please tell me where to add this piece of code, I'm new to #C. Thanks.

Comment: @Bilel-NEJI Read my post that you commented on... That has the answer.